# Circular motion after tension gets zero

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

If we have an object rotating in a vertical plane, with a cord which cannot extend (has fixed length), what happens after the tension goes to zero? How do I prove mathematically that the trajectory will be a parabola which will lie inside the circle?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you give more background on the question?

Comment: What about here @ https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/rotation-in-vertical-plane.14679/ .

Comment: [Those diagrams look familiar.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/596263/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I am just wondering at which point will the parabola stop being inside the circle?